# netbeans project and ant script

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to built a java web application at netbeans (using ant) but there is the error 
error: Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
error: Target option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 23 seconds)
I thing I have to change a 6 to 7 at built.xml but I can not find the solution,what is wrong?

Comment: Why are you creating a new web application in 2020 with Java 7? That makes no sense whatsoever. You should at least use Java 8, but Java 11 is highly recommended.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name [1] I don't think the OP is _explicitly_ wanting to create a Java 6 or Java 7 project; I suspect that they are just reacting to the somewhat confusing error message from NetBeans. [2] Sometimes if you mess with your _Java Platform_ configuation, NetBeans may automatically (re)assign a strange low value to your project's _Source/Binary Format_, as you addressed in your answer.

Comment: @skomisa: well, that can be fixed by (re)setting the used Java platform as described in my answer, but apparently that's also not what dimis wants

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to edit the IDE generated Ant script. You need to change that in the project properties.

Right click on your project (in the "Projects" window) and select Properties

In the "Sources" section you need to select JDK 7 in the drop down at the bottom:

[image]

You should also use a JDK 7 to run and test your application. You can change that in the "Libraries" section of the project (after registering the JDK 7 through Tools -> Java Platforms)

Comment: This error is when I use the java 14,I change javac.source=1.7
javac.target=1.7 I should set to 1.14?

Comment: Why do you want to set source level to 1.7 if you are using Java 14? That doesn't make sense. If you **have** to create a Java 7 project, you will need to use an older JDK.